# How to use standard UUID format

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, android-bluetooth

why I am receiving the UUID format as shown below in the logcat output? after reading about the UUID, i expected the format to be as follows

```
de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546014
```

and the code i wrote to get the UUIDs is:

```
case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID:
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID"));

        Parcelable[] extraUUID = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);

        if (extraUUID.length > 0) {
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), SubTag.msg("onReceive", "extraUUID: "+extraUUID.toString()));
        }

        break;
```

**Logcat**

```
09-18 11:35:51.622: W/BT_Receiver(8608): >>[BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID()]<<
09-18 11:35:51.622: I/BT_Receiver(8608): [onReceive()]-> extraUUID: [Landroid.os.Parcelable;@2e610c87
09-18 11:35:54.472: W/BT_Receiver(8608): >>[BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID()]<<
09-18 11:35:54.482: I/BT_Receiver(8608): [onReceive()]-> extraUUID: [Landroid.os.Parcelable;@36a16fdd
09-18 11:35:54.862: W/BT_Receiver(8608): >>[BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID()]<<
09-18 11:35:54.862: I/BT_Receiver(8608): [onReceive()]-> extraUUID: [Landroid.os.Parcelable;@34378b20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Landroid.os.Parcelable;@2e610c87
```

is the representation of `Parcelable[].toString()`. You probably want to loop on the array and call toString() to element at index. E.g.

```
for (Parcelable p : extraUUID) {
     Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), SubTag.msg("onReceive", "extraUUID: "+p.toString()))
}
```